# change the docker runtime version

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, debian, raspbian, raspbian-stretch

**tl;dr** Using `dockerd`, how do I select the `v2` runtime?

### `docker run` warning suggests v2 runtime

`docker` fails to run `docker run hello-world`. The *only* warning is *`consider using runtime v2`* found in file `/var/log/deamon.log`

```
containerd[367]: level=warning msg="runtime v1 is deprecated since containerd v1.4, consider using runtime v2" time="2020-12-30T15:49:25.426984959-08:00"
```

This is the only warning or error among all syslogs and `--debug` output, so it's my best next step.

`dockerd --help` options for `runtime` are

```
‣ dockerd --help | grep runtime
      --add-runtime runtime      Register an additional OCI compatible runtime (default [])
      --cpu-rt-runtime int       Limit the CPU real-time runtime in microseconds
      --default-runtime string   Default OCI runtime for containers (default "runc")
```

#### versions in use

Running Raspbian 9 (Debian 9) on Raspberry Pi 2.

Using `docker-ce` installation (installed using [`get-docker.sh`](https://get.docker.com/))

```
‣ dpkg --status docker-ce
Package: docker-ce
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: admin
Installed-Size: 68106
Architecture: armhf
Version: 5:19.03.14~3-0~raspbian-stretch
Replaces: docker-engine
Depends: docker-ce-cli, containerd.io (>= 1.2.2-3), iptables, libseccomp2 (>= 2.3.0), libc6 (>= 2.4), libdevmapper1.02.1 (>= 2:1.02.97), libsystemd0
Recommends: ca-certificates, cgroupfs-mount | cgroup-lite, git, pigz, xz-utils, libltdl7
Conflicts: docker (<< 1.5~), docker-engine, docker-engine-cs, docker.io, lxc-docker, lxc-docker-virtual-package
...
```

`dockerd`

```
‣ dockerd --version
Docker version 19.03.14, build 5eb3275d40
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker version 19.03 did not allow you to select the v2 runtime.

Only **Docker 20.10.0 introduced runtime v2** and uses it as its default runtime.
For more details see Docker release notes at https://docs.docker.com/engine/release-notes/#runtime-5

The details of introducing runtime v2 to Docker 20.10.0 reveal that you should be able actively select the default runtime with Docker 20.10.0 upwards by specifying `--default-runtime=com.docker.runtime.runc.v1`, see https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/41182.